# Python How Can I Make a Counter To Cycle Through a Dictionary Inside a For Loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, random, counter

I have just started coding and don't know much about it. This is my bit of code that tries to cycle through numbers from the for loop to assign num1 and num2. Instead it make a new one called num0. WHAT?!

```
import random
numbers = {'num1': '', 'num2': ''}

counter = 0
for i in range(0, 2):
    number = random.randint(0, 5)
    counter + 1
    numbers['num' + str(counter)] = number;

print(numbers)
```

Comment: `counter + 1` is an expression that adds 1 to counter and discards the result. You probably meant to assign the result back to counter: `counter = counter + 1`, or even `counter += 1`.

Comment: counter is pretty much useless as you've got the `i` variable there that is not used for anything. Rather, you should write `for counter in range(1, 3):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`counter + 1` adds 1 with the value of counter, but it never stores the result by assigning the result to `counter`. You need to assign the result to the `counter` variable, i.e. `counter = counter + 1` or even more concisely the equivalent `counter += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

`counter + 1` isn't assigned to anything. You have to do `counter += 1`. `counter + 1` returns a new number but doesn't assign it to anything. `counter += 1` returns a new number *counter + 1* and assigns it to the variable *counter*. It's the same as `counter = counter + 1`.